# Why are scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d running before the database starts listening for connections causing pg_restore failure?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

As per the "Initialization scripts" section of https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres, I have two files in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:

1. init-db.sh
2. backup.dump

init-db.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres -v "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/backup.dump"
exit
```

and it seems to execute but gets a server connection error because it seems the server hasn't started listening on port 5432 yet as the below logs files seem to indicate.

What am I doing wrong?  I essentially want to restore a database once the postgres docker container has been initialized and started running.

Once the container is running if I run the init-db.sh script manually in a terminal session, it creates the database exactly as I want...

```
2019-10-23T17:09:43.032659100Z /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/backup.dump
2019-10-23T17:09:43.032699100Z
2019-10-23T17:09:43.032704200Z /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.sh
2019-10-23T17:09:43.069092100Z pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
2019-10-23T17:09:43.069518400Z pg_restore: error: connection to database "postgres" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
2019-10-23T17:09:43.069534000Z  Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
2019-10-23T17:09:43.069538000Z  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2019-10-23T17:09:43.069540800Z could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
2019-10-23T17:09:43.069543700Z  Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
2019-10-23T17:09:43.069546600Z  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2019-10-23T17:09:45.514371200Z 2019-10-23 17:09:45.514 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.0 (Debian 12.0-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2019-10-23T17:09:45.514563000Z 2019-10-23 17:09:45.514 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2019-10-23T17:09:45.514629800Z 2019-10-23 17:09:45.514 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2019-10-23T17:09:45.522068300Z 2019-10-23 17:09:45.521 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2019-10-23T17:09:45.547131800Z 2019-10-23 17:09:45.547 UTC [23] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-10-23 17:09:42 UTC
2019-10-23T17:09:45.977904500Z 2019-10-23 17:09:45.977 UTC [23] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2019-10-23T17:09:45.980523000Z 2019-10-23 17:09:45.980 UTC [23] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/16453B0: wanted 24, got 0
2019-10-23T17:09:45.980590000Z 2019-10-23 17:09:45.980 UTC [23] LOG:  redo is not required
2019-10-23T17:09:45.994889300Z 2019-10-23 17:09:45.994 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  dev01:
    driver: bridge

services:
  webapplication2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapplication2
    depends_on:
      - "pgdev01"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApplication2/Dockerfile
    networks:
     - dev01
  pgdev01:
    image: postgres 
    restart: always 
    volumes:
      - db_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./dbscripts/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    networks:
      - dev01
volumes:
  db_volume:
```

docker-compose.override.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapplication2:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44361
    ports:
      - "61225:80"
      - "44361:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
  pgdev01:
    ports:
      - "5434:5432" 
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "redacted"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encountering this issue because you included `-h localhost` in your `init-db.sh` file.  If you remove it, things will work.

This is happening because in the default `docker-entrypoint.sh` file provided by the `postgres` image will [empty out `listen_addresses` during the initialization phase](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh#L128).  Therefore, it won't listen on `localhost`.

Disclosure: I work for [Enterprisedb (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: Awesome !! When running on the host that postgres is running on, there is no need to define the port or host AS postgres has not exposed the host yet

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres -v "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/backup.dump"
```

to

```
pg_restore -U postgres -d postgres -v "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/backup.dump"
```

fixed this. I have not idea why... It was a wild guess based the logs showing an inability to connect to postgres with the host and port...